# How to get the boost_major_version number automatically?

Tags: c++, regex, linux, ubuntu, boost

Previously on Ubuntu, we can do the following to get the `boost_major_version`:

```
echo "$boost_cv_lib_version" | sed 's/_//;s/_.*//'
```

For whatever reason, Ubuntu changes when upgrading from version 14.04 to 16.04 and now I have to do the following to find my Boost version:

```
dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
```

And the current version of boost installed using `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev` is:

```
Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
```

Given this, I would require the major version, i.e. `158`.

Other than manually looking at it knowing it's 158? I've tried some regexes but I couldn't get it correct to strip the string: `Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1` to `158`.

I've tried:

```
alvas@ubi:~/repp$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version' 
Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
alvas@ubi:~/repp$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version' | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep -oP '([0-9].*\.[0-9].*)\.' 
1.58.0.
```

But I also understand that the `-P` option might not be available on linux platforms.

I could do this by piping into Python to do the dirty string works but that's a little too much... I'm sure there's a better way:

```
alvas@ubi:~/repp$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version' | python -c "import re,sys; print re.findall(r'([0-9].*\.[0-9].*)\.[0-9].*\.', sys.stdin.readline())[0].replace('.', '')"
158
```

So the question is:

- **How do I get the `boost_major_version` on Ubuntu 16.04?**
- **If `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` is the only way to do it, how do I strip `Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1` -> `158`?**

Comment: Why don't you just include <boost/version.hpp> and use the BOOST_VERSION macro?

Comment: This is at bash command, it's used in my `./configure` script for users to install.

Comment: Configure scripts usually compile and run some  test programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the version info by querying the `dpkg` database with `dpkg-query` directly:

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Version}\n' libboost-dev
```

`--showformat` indicates we just want the value of the `Version` parameter, so you will get just the version number in the output.

Now, to answer your second question, AFAIK `dpkg` does not differentiate between the major and minor (and micro) version numbers, you need to parse that yourself. Here is a `sed` way for this case:

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Version}\n' libboost-dev | sed -E 's/^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\..*/\1\2/'
```